# How to play several Videos in sequence way in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for my ignorance but I am starting in Javascript programming and I would like to make one app to play video assets sequentially.
My app project is the following:
I have one menu and three buttons to play each video and I would like to add Javascript code for that when the user click (for example) the first button and then the second button, the apps plays the first and second video in sequence way or if the user click the second and third button the app plays the second and third video assets and so on, for it, Could anybody say me how I have to program it in Javascript code?
Hope you can understand me(sorry for my little english).
Thanks in advance

Alejandro

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of the video players here: http://html5video.org/wiki/HTML5_Player_Comparison.

Most of th eplayers listed there has JavaScript API.

Comment: Hi Shoban, First thanks for your fast answer. On the other hand and like I am new in this and I am trying to make one app for Samsung Smart TV enviromment, Do you think if this Video players would be Samsung Smart Tv compatible? How I could know it? Thanks for your help. Alejandro

Comment: I amnot sure about it. Sorry :( have to check what with samsung smart tv compatibility.

Comment: Hi Shoban,sorry to bother you again but I have a problem and like I am new in Javascript, Could you help me again? My problem is the following: at the beginning the app ran successfully and I can play in way sequence way but if I want to play sequentially several times without go out the app, it does not play them in sequence way. I guess I should to add some code to reset the app and that it started again each time that I choose some sequence video(for example if I choose Video1 and Video2 and the reset the apps to can choose another sequence) Can you understand me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using a Samsung Smart TV, Yes of course, I can send you the code, please let know how I could sent it to you. By email? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I am sending to you by email the JS file. Thanks for your help again !

Comment: Hmm I don't actually know if this should be deleted or not... maybe listing them out in the answer would be better?